# How to change gVim icon on Windows?

Tags: gvim, microsoft-windows

When open gvim, there is a small icon `Vim` in the title plus buffer name.

I'd like to be able to hack anything about vim, including being able to change this gvim's icon. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem by reading the doc at [`:h windows-icon`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/os_win32.txt.html#windows-icon):

> ```
>                   *windows-icon*
> Q. I don't like the Vim icon, can I change it?
> A. Yes, place your favorite icon in bitmaps/vim.ico in a directory of
>    'runtimepath'.  For example ~/vimfiles/bitmaps/vim.ico.
> ```